# Can I ask Google to return single search result from each domain?

Tags: google-search

Can I ask Google to return single search result from each domain?

For example, when I search `php`, it returns 3 results from php.net, e.g.

- **www.php.net/**,
- **php.net/downloads.php**, and
- **php.net/manual/en/index.php**

Can I ask Google to only return **one** result from php.net?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can! It is possible to get results from only one domain by

`"search-query" site:php.net`

With this you will get only search results from php.net. But your condition doesn't seem to fit any of these Google search operator combinations!